# The def keyword always seems to give me an error feedback

Tags: python-3.7

```
def my_function(country = "Norway"):
  print("I am from " + country)

my_function("Sweden")
my_function("India")
my_function()
my_function("Brazil")
```

> Syntax Error: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be working.

I tried below in PyCharm IDE, It worked for me.

```
def my_function(country = "Norway"):
    print("I am from " + country)
my_function("Sweden")

# Output = I am from Sweden
```

Tried below code from Command line:

```
C:\Users\OmkarJ>python
Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:57:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def my_function(country = "Norway"):
...     print("I am from " + country)
...
>>> my_function("Sweden")
I am from Sweden
>>> my_function("India")
I am from India
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Omar. Well ,I don't know if this is from my python shell version which is a 3.7 .At my end it still is giving me an error feedback . Will send you next how the output looks like

Comment: Can I know the python shell or interface you use for coding , so I could use the same and save myself the inconvenience .Thank you

Comment: I would recommend PyCharm IDE, Its best.

Comment: I have added code in the above which I tried on Command line and it also worked.